# Installing Jffmpeg to JMF

Tags: video, jmf

I'm using JMF in my application. I'm trying to install jffmpeg since I'm encountering the format not supported exception. I've tried following this http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/download.html but I got lost. I enter JMF registry ok but what should I do to include the new codecs? (Also when I press Add "Could not add item" comes up... I'm running on Windows 7).

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Jffmpeg. I used Fobs4JMF. http://fobs.sourceforge.net/f4jmf_first.html. Easy to use since the jmf.properties file is configured ready for Fobs4JMF so no installation or registering, just copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

This is even better I think, simpler to use and probably more professional: http://www.humatic.de/htools/dsj.htm

Answer (score 0):

To register new codecs you have to include jffmpeg-1.1.0.jar in the liblaries path first, then register

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about codecs, but at least you cannot use JMF for capturing images on Windows 7. Try it on an XP virtual PC (VMWare will work for sure)